# cauchy sequence ${a_n}$ in $(0,1)$, ${f(a_n)}$ is also cushy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable real valued function on $(0,1)$, and $f'(x)$ is bounded on $(0,1)$, then, I think for every cauchy sequence ${a_n}$ in $(0,1)$, ${f(a_n)}$ is also cushy sequence.

This is because of mean value theorem.

My question is,
if $f'(x)$ is not bounded, then, could you tell me the counter example of this statement?
That is, cushy sequence which does not converge in $(0,1)$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ on $(0,1)$. $(\frac  1n)$ is a Cauchy sequence but $(f(\frac  1n))$ is not Cauchy.